# infinite loop with threading: threads enumerating to infinite

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

i have written my first threading script in python, so i am very new to multithreading. I have a while True infinite loop and 12 threads that do something every n seconds. What happens is that every time the loop is repeated, thread's numbers increase (first run from 1 to 12, second from 13 to 24 till huge numbers) etc. I guess the number it's just the "name" of the thread, in fact at the end of each run i call threading.activeCount() and i get 1 (the main thread i guess).

At the end of the script i also call join to make sure threads have finished their job so since at the end of each run i have 1 thread only, i guess i shouldn't worry when after hours of execution threads get numbers like 10000...

Am i wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code?  These sorts of problems should be fixed, and are usually pretty easy to identify.

Comment: I would appreciate, if you post some code. This would simplify the question..